# automatically reboot windows 7 if it cannot ping an ip address

Tags: windows-7, batch, ping

[Automatically reboot Windows8 if no internet activity](https://superuser.com/questions/767978/automatically-reboot-windows8-if-no-internet-activity)

I found the above link which helped with my question but the above solution does not work in my situation.  is there a way to restart a pc if i am not able to ping an ip address and i recieve a message "destination host unreachable?"

when i run the batch file

```
ping 192.168.1.1
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 SHUTDOWN -R -T 00
```

everything works correctly if there is no internet activity. but when i disconnect my network and run the batch file i receive a message of "reply from x.x.x.x: desnation host unreachable. and the batch file does not work.  is there a way to make the batchfile command work with i recieve a message of "destination host unreachable"?

Answer (score 0):

Rebooting seems to be an extreme solution to the problem.  You may lose work that way.  Why not disable the network interface, wait 10 seconds, and enable it again?  Alfredo's answer to this question may be useful to you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3050898/how-to-check-if-ping-responded-or-not-in-a-batch-file

Comment: Thank you Chris.... i added | find "TTL" from the link that posted above and it worked... Thank you very much for your help.