# Automatically reboot Windows if USB storage/drive is inaccessible?

Tags: windows, bitlocker

I have a media server (Windows 10) located in a very inconvenient part of my house. Occasionally, the electricity went out and everything automatically switched to battery backup.

The issue is the battery backup for the external HDD doesn't switch fast enough. Making the PC loses connection with it for a split second, thus it stays in bitlocker locked. and I am forced to reboot windows 10 so bitlocker automatically unlocks all USB storage again.

I would love to have it check itself every 5-10 minutes and auto reboot if it is unable to access a given usb storage/drive.

Any ideas how to accomplish this?

basically like this old post (the formatting of this post also follow that post) [Automatically reboot Windows if no internet connectivity](https://superuser.com/questions/767978/automatically-reboot-windows-if-no-internet-connectivity) but instead checking for internet, its checking whether it can access the usb storage/drive.

Comment: Frame challenge… why does a media server that never leaves the building need encryption?

Comment: @Tetsujin its not uncommon. We do it for our customers too. Sometimes the reason is ISO certification vs theft.

Comment: Rather than reboot the whole PC, I'd make it 'reboot' the external drive using something like https://www.yepkit.com/products/ykush.

Comment: Instead of rebooting, run *Control Panel > System and Security > BitLocker Drive Encryption*. If the drive is shown as locked, unlock it using the BitLocker password.
Several options will be shown. Click "Turn on auto-unlock". This should make it so the USB will be unlocked automatically when it finally comes up.

Comment: @harrymc unfortunately its already turned on. thats why it auto unlocks when rebooted.

Answer (score 0):

Make a battery the power for the HDD, on constant charge. Many drives use 12 VDC, and an inexpensive 12 V [sealed lead-acid](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01E706VAQ) or [lithium](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0BJVHMV7W) (examples) battery would provide truly *uninterruptible* power. That is the technique used in many home routers, for example.

This calls for minimal electrical knowledge... **and the appropriate charger for the battery**.

Comment: it already have battery power. The issue is the battery backup for the external HDD doesn't switch fast enough. Making the PC loses connection with it for a split second, thus it stays in bitlocker locked. and I am forced to reboot windows 10 so bitlocker automatically unlocks all USB storage again.

Comment: assuming the issue is the switching. not sure if it actually outputs unstable DC for a split second when it lost AC power.

Comment: Not talking about a UPS, but a 12 V battery directly on the power line to the HDD. There is **no** switching. See Online Double Conversion, https://www.vertiv.com/en-emea/about/news-and-insights/articles/educational-articles/what-are-the-different-types-of-ups-systems/

Comment: Instead of a battery I would use some large capacitors for 12V, that should stabilize the power supply of the external HDD. Capacitors don't have any problems being charged 24/7.

Comment: @Robert, Yes, capacitors have a longer service life than batteries... but the instant they start to discharge, voltage drops logarithmically, unlike a battery. If the HDD internal power supply can handle the voltage drop, a supercapacitor would be useful, otherwise, not. Of course,  a continuously online UPS would also work.

Comment: im not sure whether the issue is the switching speed or something else (maybe unstable DC output the first time AC power loss?). the device is the usual DC "mini ups" like this one https://www.amazon.com/SDPower-12000maH-Uninterruptible-System-Camera/dp/B00CIO5L8M/ref=sr_1_13?crid=HANAWN4XUM6C&keywords=mini+ups+dc&qid=1687857626&sprefix=mini+ups+d%2Caps%2C379&sr=8-13 often used for wifi routers. Yes an online UPS would be better, but its outside of my budget.

Answer (score 0):

The manage-bde -unlock command should be used every 5 minutes (doesn't hurt to repeat it). Like this:

```
manage-bde -unlock x: -rp 123456-234...48digit-recoverypassword
```

Execute it through task scheduler, executor: system, trigger: every x minutes

Comment: thankyou, that would work. but unfortunately adds another problem: exposing the recovery password in plaintext

Comment: That is no problem. Put that command into a script and make it accessible to the system account (task executor) only. The system account may query the numerical recovery password, anyway, so having a plain text file accessible exclusively to it does not lower security at all. Even when you write it into the task it will only be accessible to task owners (admins, system).